# Is it possible to edit Metadata in AccessListEntryView after added folder (or file) in FutureAccessList

Tags: c#, uwp, metadata, token

Title tells quite clearly my needs. So is it possible to edit Metadata in AccessListEntryView after added folder (or file) in a FutureAccessList. Looks like that Metadata as well as Token are read only. Using Folder- or FilePicker once again to make changes in Metadata doesn't meet my needs.

I use metadata to store "Frendy Named Folder" instead to show a full path of folder or file to make some things more clear to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is it possible to edit Metadata in AccessListEntryView after added folder (or file) in a FutureAccessList.

As far as I know, you can't edit the metadata of [AccessListEntry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.accesslistentry.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

You can only add [StorageFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx) / [StorageFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.aspx) to  [StorageItemAccessList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageitemaccesslist.aspx) / [StorageItemMostRecentlyUsedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageitemmostrecentlyusedlist.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or remove them.

Comment: I feared something like this so I solved the problem making (adding) the information in a config file. Thanks for your answer.